# Cannot get value from sessionStorage.getItem in cordova

Tags: json, cordova

I use cordova for my hybrid mobile app, so i use sessionStorage to store some items from remote like this :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", setStorage, false);
function setStorage() {

    $.each(post, function(i, item){
        $.ajax({
            url: item,
            cache: false,
            success:function(data){
                donnee = JSON.stringify(data);
                sessionStorage.setItem(i, donnee);
            }
            ,error: function(){
                console.log('Error ');
           }
       })
   })
}
```

I verified that all data are saved successfully from remote to sessionstorage, and want to get item as this :

```
eventsData = sessionStorage.getItem('events')
```

This returns "null"

For the app i use, onsenUi as UI, angular data manipulation.

Someone have an idea, why this returns null?

Thanks

Comment: you are using correct key to get an item? put one alert in success function and check again.

Comment: Yes i have correct key, and in success function, all items are stored sucessfully with sessionStorage.setItem(i, donnee);

Comment: When i reload the app with Ctrl+R on chrome device inspector, eventsData = sessionStorage.getItem('events') returns the data, but i want to get it directly when users access the app home page without refreshing again the app.

Comment: then you try local storage

Comment: Is it possible to clear localstorage when user leave the app?

Comment: detect back button usage and then you manually clear the local storage